# TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable GetColorImage object

Tags: python, typeerror

i have following situation:

cratecolor.py: (code stripped to its minimum...)

```
import ... ...


class GetColorImage:  
    def __init__(self, ia=None):
        self.path = None
        self.img = None
        self.img0 = None
        self.s = None
        self.basetime = 0
        self.count = 0
        self.stride = 32
        self.ia = ia
        self.img_size = 640
        self.auto = True
        self.getImage()

    def getImage(self):
        self.ia.remote_device.node_map.ExposureTime.value = 350
        self.ia.remote_device.node_map.Gain.value = 150
    
        ...
        ...

        print(color, l)        # prints: 1 59.64829339143065

        return color, l
```

main.py: (code stripped to its minimum)

```
...
...

 # code exectued on a qthread:

 def getcolor(self, idin):
    color, lightness = cratecolor.GetColorImage(ia=self.ia) #******
    print(color, lightness)
```

In the line marked with ***** i get the error message   `color, lightness = cratecolor.GetColorImage(ia=self.ia) TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable GetColorImage object` but i dont get why.
any help appreciated.

Comment: You forgot to call the `getImage` method.

Comment: @Lecdi thanks for your answer, that one is called by the init.. is there a way to call the class, and return multiple values?

Comment: You are returning values from getImage method, not from init method. When you are creating a object using `cratecolor.GetColorImage(ia=self.ia)` it returns only single object, you're expecting 2 values that's why you are getting error. Btw init cannot return anything

Comment: Add method `def __iter__(self): return iter(self.getImage())`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot return values from an `__init__` function, so you instead must either:

1. Call the `getImage()` method when creating the class
2. Define an `__iter__` method for the class to automatically allow you to assign it to multiple variables.

The second one is probably the better solution. Here is the method you would add to the class for it to work:

```py
def __iter__(self):
    return iter(self.getImage())
```

Comment: this worked like a charm. thank you for your time and explanation. very clear

Answer (score 1):

You're returning a GetColorImage object, not the two values you're actually looking for. The return statement in getImage() just returns the values to your constructor and does nothing with them. The constructor finishes and the whole GetColorImage object is returned. If you try to return something else from the constructor, you'll get an error.

You could just create the object and then call getImage():

```
colorObj = cratecolor.GetColorImage(ia=self.ia)
color, lightness = colorObj.getImage()
```

As pointed out below, you can just chain them if you don't need the object:

```
color, lightness = cratecolor.GetColorImage(ia=self.ia).getImage()
```

Comment: No need of two statements, color and lightness can be retrieved just by chaining `getImage` method to call of class

Comment: Good point. My brain went straight to "It's creating an object, lets use the object." Added to answer.

Answer (score 1):

To unpack a object, you must ensure that it is iterable:

```
>>> class Foo:
...     def __iter__(self): return iter(range(2))
... 
>>> a, b = Foo()
>>> a
0
>>> b
1
```

So, you should make your class iteratable:

```
class GetColorImage:
    ...
    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.getImage())
```